# Charset UTF-8 not working on AWS Production PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, encoding, utf-8

On my local machine, the special characters such as `ó, í, ù` etc... are showing. Once i uploaded it to production (AWS Elastic Beanstalk) it started showing the typical question marks (?).

On the header i have the following:

```
<html lang="es">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Which in theory, should be enough to be working. On the developer console (chrome) i put `document.characterSet` which the output was `UTF-8`. The problem remains the same on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. The files are saved with with `UTF-8` encoding also. Is there anything i am missing?

On the rest of the website, the characters are showing fine. Anything inside the `body` tag. Anything on my `header` tag, it shows the questions marks. On local env, everything works fine.

Aditionally, this only happens on the home page. When i visit another internal page, it works fine, it shows the special characters on the header.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Website: http://bulevar.pe

Comment: Are you using htmlentities or database to print data on the page?

Comment: i am using Laravel 5.4, so htmlentities i guess, anything inside the `body` tags, the characters show normal, only on the `header` is not showing (meta tags)